# Complex numbers: what is the formal name for the graph representing all points after applying a function/transformation?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am talking about this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD0NjbwqlYw) at 8:50. Is there a formal name for the graph after applying a function to all points in the complex plane?

Comment: The image......

Comment: @Jp McCarthy What I am looking for is the specific diagram used in the video to represent the image. The reason I am looking for it is that the same diagram is used in other videos as well and I find myself not really getting the intuition of the diagram. The author of the video refers to it as "radio lines" sometimes but I can't find anything by Googling.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood.